# add mouse listener to a draw string text

Tags: java

I want to add a mouse listener to a text. Is it posiible?
Thanks

```
BufferStrategy bs=this.getBufferStrategy();

if(bs==null){
    createBufferStrategy(3);
    return;
}

Graphics g=bs.getDrawGraphics();

g.fillRect(0, 0, 800, 400);

g.setFont(new Font("Verdana",0 ,50));
g.setColor(Color.WHITE);

g.drawString("Play", 600, 60);
```

Answer (score 1):

As your `Graphics` object does not know about the individual "items" on it, you can't add an listener to the text "Play" per se.

Approach one would be to not use one "big" `Graphics` objects but to have an individual component for the "Play" text. You could attach a listener to this smaller component.
Another approach would be to add an listener to the "big" component and query the click event for the mouse coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this.

```
 final JTextField textField = new JTextField("Text goes here");
        textField.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
                //take some action here
            }
        });
```